# add carousel in jquery mobile with google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I wanted to create a page on jquery mobile with google map.

something like this:
[Reference from Omar](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/N6PAh/)

but with a carousel below the page where you can scroll and choose the pins from.

I tried using [owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) with the demo codes, css and html but it doesn't seem to be working, or rather, it doesn't display on the screen.

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <a class="item link"><h1>1</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>2</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>3</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>4</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>5</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>6</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>7</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>8</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>9</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>10</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>11</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>12</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>13</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>14</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>15</h1></a>
  <a class="item link"><h1>16</h1></a>
</div>
```

Appreciate if anyone could help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owl carousel seems to work quite nicely with jQM.  Just create one div for your map and another for your carousel. Place them as wanted and initialize both in the pagecreate or container beforeshow:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        items: 4,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 4],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [1080, 3],
        itemsTablet: [768, 2],
        itemsMobile: [450, 1]
    });

    loadMap("#map-canvas");
});
```

Ensure that you are referencing the owl css files in your page as well as the js file.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/77rtb/3/)**

Comment: @Omar, I'm sure yours will be great!

Comment: It will be a mess, trust me ;)